# Interop Word - Show splash screen

Tags: c#, ms-word, com, splash-screen

I need to open Word document through Interop with following code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordApp.Documents.Open("filename.docx");
```

However, all times I open a document, splash screen of word is never shown.

Instead, if I open the document with System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("filename.docx") the splash screen appears correctly.

Is there some way to say to word application class to show the splash screen?

[image]

Comment: The Interop is designed as an Interface to Word, which is the reason why the splash screen is hidden. If you want to make Word visible, use wordApp.Visible = true;

Comment: seems like most people would rather [want the opposite](https://lifehacker.com/5877847/start-microsoft-office-programs-without-the-splash-screen) :)

Comment: I aleady use wordApp.Visible = true. The document open correctly, but I'm not able to show the splash screen (starting up..).

Comment: would it be an option if you do use the `Process.Start` approach, and then COM-connect to the document once it is open?

Comment: No. I can't use Process.Start. I'm force to use Intero only.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you want the splash screen to show?

Comment: It is useful for the final user as feedback about word is opening. I've no time to create a custom splash screen and it doesn't make sense build another one since word offers one.

Comment: Sorry, mate. You cannot get the splash screen to show when starting through automation. `Process.Start` followed by `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` is the only way to get a splash screen and also get an automation reference. It's fragile, though (as is automation as a whole).

Comment: Thank you Michael. For sure I know word automation is fragile, however due to many different reasons, at this time I can't write differents solutions.